# C# Opening csv string in Excel without saving the string

Tags: c#, excel, csv, interop

I have a string in csv format, that I wish to simply open in Excel, without first having to save the file.

Is this possible?  I've had a look at Interop but I cannot find the specific method that I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just copy the values over manually. You can find a sample [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084).

Adapting that sample to get a very short sample to get you started (please note, this sample is not complete and you need to read the complete sample to see how to do things properly):

```
Excel.Application oXL= new Excel.Application();
oXL.Visible = true;
Excel._Workbook oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add( Missing.Value ));
Excel._Worksheet oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = [first value from csv];
```

But assuming that it's a range of values in the csv string, just do a `String.Split` on it and then use the array to populate a `Range` in the sheet, just check out the sample in the article for details.

Comment: I did try that but it is very very slow when I have a large file.  When I save the file using File.WriteAllText(), it is very quick.  I wanted similar performance, but opening straight from the csvString rather than saving.  I suppose I could save and open the file, then delete the file.

Comment: @Darren. Yes, if it's a big file it'll be a lot faster to save & open rather than to copy all the values manually. If you worry about cluttering up the hard drive, as you said, just delete the file afterwards (and maybe use [GetTempFilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) to create the filename to not have to worry about where to create it)

Comment: @Darren: Check out the answer I've posted. I had the same performance-issue as you. About 1500 records (15 cols) and cell by cell it took about 7 or 8 minutes. AfterI converted my data into a 2-dimensional array it took about 5 or 10 seconds so it might be worth to give it a try.

Comment: Performance can be improved by temporarily turning of ScreenUpdating and Calculation while your code runs. see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948739/how-to-show-a-wait-screen-in-vba-excel-2010/4953494#4953494) for example

Comment: @Chris Does it make any difference if Excel is visible or not? I have to check my code for that but I don't think dat I've turned of those 2 things, but Excel was set invisible.

Comment: @Koen i've not tried that one, easy to test with a simple experiment. I'd be interested to know the result

Comment: @Koen i did a small experiment comparing performance by off Application.ScreenUpdating, Application.EnableEvents, Application.Calculation, Application.Visible.  Turning off ScreenUpdating, EnableEvents and Calculation reduced execution time of my test case by 95%.  Visible off made insignificant difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you convert your csv-string to a 2-dimensional array first, you can pass it to a range of cells.

```
Excel.Range oRange = oSheet.Range("A1",Missing.Value);
oRange.Resize(myArray.GetLength(0),myArray.GetLength(1));
oRange.Value = myArray;
```

This code is written out of my mind, so I hope It's ok, but I think you get the picture.
If you like to include a header in your excel-file, just start the range from A2 instaed of A1.